# How to label encode the column index in the data-set table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to label encode the second column I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong?
I'm able to encode the first column

```
    data.head()
        area_type   availability    location    size    society total_sqft  bath    balcony price
    0   Super built-up Area 19-Dec  Electronic City Phase II    2 BHK   Coomee  1056    2.0 1.0 39.07
    1   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Chikka Tirupathi    4 Bedroom   Theanmp 2600    5.0 3.0 120.00
    2   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Uttarahalli 3 BHK   NaN 1440    2.0 3.0 62.00
    3   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Lingadheeranahalli  3 BHK   Soiewre 1521    3.0 1.0 95.00
    4   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Kothanur    2 BHK   NaN 1200    2.0 1.0 51.00
enc = LabelEncoder()
data.iloc[:,2] = enc.fit_transform(data.iloc[:,2])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-53fda4a71b5e> in <module>()
      1 enc = LabelEncoder()
----> 2 data.iloc[:,2] = enc.fit_transform(data.iloc[:,2])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    110         """
    111         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 112         self.classes_, y = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
    113         return y
    114 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    208     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    209     if axis is None:
--> 210         return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    211     if not (-ar.ndim <= axis < ar.ndim):
    212         raise ValueError('Invalid axis kwarg specified for unique')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    272 
    273     if optional_indices:
--> 274         perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')
    275         aux = ar[perm]
    276     else:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

I want to label encode the second column "Location", If I use `data.iloc[:,1] = enc.fit_transform(data.iloc[:,1])` indexing I can label encode availability column, So
How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have `NaNs` in your `location` column?

Comment: No, I checked there is no NaNs in my location column @ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the datatype of your column?

The error arises because the label encoder cannot order numbers (and `np.nan` are floats) and strings.

To fix this you can:
- Replace any nan with an empty string `data['col_name'].fillna('',inplace=True)`;
- Convert the column to a string by typing `data['col_name'] = data['col_name'].astype(str)`

Comment: I guess Its a string, I tried your method still getting same error.

Comment: area_type        object
availability     object
location         object
size             object
society          object
total_sqft       object
bath            float64
balcony         float64
price           float64
dtype: object

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to deal with location or availability? And from what you wrote, both of them are objects and not strings. This means that there is a mixed datatype, and the label encoder cannot order them into a list.

Usually this happens either when you have numbers and strings, or when you have nans. For nans, have you tried to do `data['col_name'].isnull().sum()`? This should tell you if there is any nan in it.

Comment: I'm trying to deal with location. I found 1 Nan by using your command and tried to delete that row using data = data[pd.notnull(data['location'])] later I got zero Nan but when I tried to label encode the location column I'm getting the same error as before

Comment: this is the data set https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xNs7f_HC64Pvfe_M9Ai-f5NQUr3t-N6y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the datatype of the new column?

I think you can also simply do:
`data['location'].fillna('', inplace=True)` to replace the nan value with a blank space,
Then make sure that the column is a string:
`data['availability'] = data['availability'].astype(str)`
And finally trying again to label encode the variable